# Reference a Range using column number rather than column letter

Tags: vba

I feel like this should be simple because I have found a million references online on how to do this. I've tried several different combos to no avail.

I am simply trying to reference a column using the LastCol variable within a range, but keep getting the error below. The error occurs on the line labeled with a ->. I've tried several different variations, including using the letter name for the first range paramter with a colon, comma, moving the quotes around, putting "." before the Cells references, etc. Every time I look up how to do this online, it seems like I am doing it right.

[image: error message]

This is my code:

```
Public Sub cmb_orgname_Change()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim orgname As String
Dim org_position As Double
Dim LastCol, LastRow As Integer
Dim prod_range As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set sht = Sheet1

'get the value of the selected org name from the dropdown
orgname = sht.OLEObjects("cmb_orgname").Object.Value

'find the last column for the number of org names, currently this is not being utilized
LastCol = Sheet3.Range("F2").End(xlToRight).Column

If orgname <> "" Then
    Call Clear_ComboBox
    -> org_position = WorksheetFunction.Match(orgname, Sheet3.Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(2, LastCol)), 0) + 6
    LastRow = Sheet3.Cells(Sheet3.Rows.Count, org_position).End(xlUp).Row
    Set prod_range = Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(3, org_position), Sheet3.Cells(LastRow, org_position))
    
    
    For Each cell In prod_range
        With sht.OLEObjects("cmb_prodname").Object
            Dim test As String
            test = CStr(cell.Value)
            .AddItem CStr(cell.Value)
        End With
    Next cell
    
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to put ``Sheet3`` before each ``Cells`` like you have on ``prod_rangeprod``

Comment: I had tried that, but unfortunately it did not work. I did just figure something out though! I am about to post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

after many different iterations of different searches, I found a function called ADDRESS() that comes after a range. With the ADDRESS function, I was able to make this work! Basically, all I had to do was change my line to the following:

`org_position = WorksheetFunction.Match(orgname, Sheet3.Range("F2:" & Sheet3.Cells(2, LastCol).Address()), 0) + 6`

And now it is running smoothly. This is the page I found the ADDRESS function and information on: https://software-solutions-online.com/use-vba-range-address-method/

Comment: `Sheet3.Range("F2", Sheet3.Cells(2, LastCol))`.